# Searching CSV file for value and giving output

Tags: javascript, csv, search

Is there a way to search a CSV file in Javascript for a string and output something depending on fetched results without converting the CSV file to a array?

Comment: Why don't you want to convert it to an array?

You could alway pull it in as a string and use .includes() on it.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: I was hoping to plot the values associated with the string on a chart using chartjs

Comment: You should be able to do that with an array. Not sure why you're trying to avoid the array.